# HTML/CSS - Inconsistent a href

Tags: html, css

Please refer to my page http://vault-x.com/v3/contact.html

```
Contact me via email: hello[at]vault-x.com
```

`Follow Vault-X on Twitter`

Both of these links should have the same link style, the top is correct but the bottom is not.

Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: They are the same for me. Which browser are you using and what is wrong? Could you have a stale CSS in your browser cache?

Comment: It would be better to show us your markup and css here rather than referring to a location that may no longer be available in the future thus rendering this question and answer less than useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have the same style, by default. However if you visit one and then return to this page, their style will be different. You need to be sure to set the styles for:

```
a:visited { /* ... */ }
```

You appear to be writing over old styles as well:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
  color: #663300;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* ... */

a.menu:link, a:visited, a:active {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Perhaps on the bottom set of selectors you meant `a.menu:link, a.menu:visited, a.menu:active` instead of dropping the `.menu` class after the first selector.